# SBApplication : how to send raw data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appleevents, scripting-bridge

I woudl like to send raw data (a void*) using SBApplication sendEvent

Unfortunaltly I've found no documentation about this.

Do you have any idea to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for yoru help,

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendEvent:id:parameters:` is actually a message that all SBObjects respond to, not just SBApplications. SBObject.h says:

> ```
> // Send an Apple event.  The direct parameter is the specifier of the receiver if it
> // is non-null.  Other parameters are given using "parameters:" as a list of pairs
> // of the parameter four-byte code followed by an Objective-C object; use a parameter
> // code of 0 to mark the end of the list.
> ```

So, try boxing the data up into an NSData object, and passing that.